# find the file path of the code

Tags: template-hints

we are using custom payment method. under payment method we can see that payment method.

when i inspect element, i can see following code is reason to  display the payment method.

```
<input id ="p_method_byte" value = " byte" type = "radio" name = "payment" onclick " payment.switchMethod('byte') class = "radio" autocomplete= "off">
```

i want to know from which file this code is coming. i tried template path hints, but that did't worked.

i want to know where this code is present in folder in "Block", "controllers", "helper", "model"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Payment methods code coming bellow file.

```
app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml
```

OR

```
app\design\frontend\your_package\your_theme\template\checkout\onepage\payment\methods.phtml
```